# WebView issues on migrating Awesomium 1.6.6 to 1.7.1

Tags: awesomium

I'm migrating code from Awesomium 1.6.6 to 1.7.1, which loads a url and saves it as a png.
Wondering about a few issues:

1. Does setting WebView.Source implicitly load the page (Apparently does, judging from the provided sample)?
2. WebView.ResourceRequest was used to set the request to post and push some form data into it. In the 1.7.1 way I attach a ResourceInterceptor to WebCore and raise an event to be caught by WebViews and screened against the ProcessId. But, is there any way to attach a ResourceInterceptor to a WebView to make this simpler?
3. WebView.RequestScrollData() and WebView.ScrollDataReceived were used to get width/height data for resize. Is that supposed to be taken from WebView.Height/Width now? and, when is it guaranteed to be set (i.e. on LoadingFrameComplete, etc)?
4. How can I detect that a resize has ended, i.e. the former WebView.ResizeComplete event?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is embarrassing, I'm kinda talking to myself...

So I figured out the answers for the last two issues:

Getting the size should be done through a JavaScript code executed from the WebView's LoadingFrameComplete event:

> ```
>     WebView _view;
>     _view.LoadingFrameComplete += LoadingFrameCompleteHandler;
>
>     private void LoadingFrameCompleteHandler(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (e.IsMainFrame)
>         {
>             var view = (WebView)sender;
>             var js = "(function() { some js code to return size }) ();";
>             var size = view.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(js);
>
>             if (size != JSValue.Null && size != JSValue.Undefined)
>             {
>                 var values = (JSValue[])size;
>                 int width = (int)values[0];
>                 int height = (int)values[1];
>                 view.Resize(width, height);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

This is how you catch the resize:

> ```
>     WebView view;
>     ((BitmapSurface)view.Surface).Resized += YourResizeHandler;
> ```